# Laravel 5.4 DELETE photos from public path

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

When on delete i want to delete not only row from the table, i also want to delete file from the public path. This is my code:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $photo = Photo::find($id);
        Storage::delete(public_path('/photos/' . $photo->photo));
        $photo->delete();

        return back();
    }
```

Can some one tell me what im doing wrong?

i use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;`

Also i use `Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;` for storing photo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out, it seems like it would be the right solution.

https://laravel.io/forum/06-04-2014-how-to-delete-an-image-file-when-deleting-a-page?page=1

Comment: what is File:: ? is it a laravel extension? Sorry im new in laravel.